# TCA select-fileFolder backend.css design

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

For an extension I created a fileFolder select field:

```
"image" => Array (  
    'label' => "LLL:EXT:my_collection/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_mycollection_domain_model_mycollection.image",
    'config' => Array (
        'type' => 'select',
        'items' => Array (
            Array('',0),
            ),
        'fileFolder' => 'produktbilder',
        'fileFolder_extList' => 'jpg,jpeg',
        'fileFolder_recursions' => 0,
        'size' => 15,
        'minitems' => 0,
        'maxitems' => 1,
        'renderType' => 'selectSingle',
    ),
),
```

With this I get a list of all files in the folder `produktbilder` as a selectlist. And when I select one I see a small Icon next to it.

The problem is, this icon is too small. There are 2 CSS directive in backend.css that cause this:

```
.input-group-icon {
    width: 32px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.input-group-icon img {
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 28px;
}
```

What I would like now to do is overwrite this with:

```
.input-group-icon {
    width: 150px;
}
.input-group-icon img {
    max-height: none;
}
```

But just overwriting this in the backend.css is not a nice solution. For examples it makes the language icon field in the language selection wider too.

I can not find any settings to set a custom class or a custom style or something so that I can style only this field.

Any idea?

Comment: Hello, You can try this - [Skinning API](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/SkinningReference/BackendCssApi/SkinningApi/Index.html).

Comment: @RobertG. Thanks, With this I still do not have an extra class or something to identify my field and only my field.

Comment: Yes, I understand. I mean, this is not possible without update Typo3 core.